# Find a location nearby on mobile or desktop for a multi-location local business

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, location

I need to implement a feature on our landing pages so users can enter their address or opt to use current location and we will display the location of our business nearest to the address entered or their current location.

I've read about the Google places API web service but I only need to look up the locations for our specific business, around 35 total brick and mortar stores spread across 5 major metros.

I've also read multiple answers on here about how to do this in a mobile app but this implementation is for a responsive website.

I also found the [Google GeoLocation API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/obtain-location?hl=en) which will auto-detect the users location but I am not sure if it allows the user to enter a different location in case they are looking up a location that is close to their home address while they are at work for example.

The site is running on Wordpress.

Comment: Could it be something like this that you need? https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-find-your-nearest/    or https://wordpress.org/plugins/store-locator-le/

Comment: Quite possibly.  I'm reviewing that plugin today. Great find!

Comment: There are plenty more like it and several bits of code on SO showing ho to write code for that. Good luck!

Comment: This was the post on SO with code for locating nearest places if you were looking at a DIY solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279559/geolocation-closest-locationlat-long-from-my-position